# How can I access C/C++ variables in inline assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

Here is some code that I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
int main(){
asm("\nmov dword [rsp],70\n");
cout << a;}
```

In the code above, I try to write to my integer (a) by writing to the location pointed to by `esp` (the stack pointer). This should work since that is where the variable is actually located. But when I try to compile the program using the command

```
g++ prog.cpp -masm=intel
```

I get the following error:

```
prog.cpp: Assembler messages:
prog.cpp:6: Error: ambiguous operand size for `mov'
```

I have also tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a=5;
int main(){
asm(
"\npop rax\n"
"inc rax\n"
"push rax\n"
);
cout << a;}
```

The main difference between this program and the previous one is that instead of using `esp` to access the stack, I used `push` and `pop`. This code compiles. But when I run it, it just returns 5 – the same number we started with!

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong in the programs above?

Comment: Thank you very much! The first program now compiles, but it prints 0 instead of 70.

Comment: `int a = 0; asm ("movl $70, %[a]": [a] "=rm"(a) ::); printf("%d\n", a);`

Comment: *"I try to write to my integer (`a`) by writing to the location pointed to by `esp`"* - `a` is not on the stack - it's a global variable.

Comment: @TonyD So where is a really located?

Comment: @Brandon Thank you again! It works! Can you please explain, in an answer, why it works?

Comment: For a (very) detailed explanation of how inline asm works, let me suggest the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: @IsaacD.Cohen traditionally, in the [Data Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data).